# Assign map objects in Smarty

Tags: smarty

I have the following code and **I want to assign each map object smarty**. How can I assign it? Any kind of help will be highly appreciated.

```
<?php
$MAP_OBJECT->getHeaderJS();
$MAP_OBJECT->getMapJS();
$MAP_OBJECT->printOnLoad();
$MAP_OBJECT->printMap();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simple do:

```
$smarty->assign('MAP_OBJECT', $MAP_OBJECT);
```

and then in your template file you can use:

```
{$MAP_OBJECT->getHeaderJS()}
{$MAP_OBJECT->getMapJS()}
{$MAP_OBJECT->printOnLoad()}
{$MAP_OBJECT->printMap()}
```